# Corona SDK call function from file inside a folder

Tags: lua, directory, coronasdk

Im using the Corona SDK.

Here is an example of my file directory...

```
- Project Folder
-- file.lua
-- Another Folder
--- another_file.lua 
-- main.lua
```

*I just started using Corona 4 days ago, so let me know if i missed something in the explanation.*

So now were in `main.lua` and im using `newGroup()` to display my content.

I want to call the `new()` function from `file.lua` so i write, `localGroup:insert(file.new())`. And this works great.

Now when i want to call the `new()` function from the `another_file.lua`, `localGroup:insert(another_file.new())`, i get an error.

It has something to do with the file being nested in another folder. How can I write this to make it work?

Comment: Can you put an example of the contents of file.lua and another_file.lua ? The file.new() call should not work, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry, but you must put all your .lua files in the root directory where the main.lua is located, else you'll get errors. one of the drawbacks of corona is that you can only put images in subfolders, but other .lua files, movies, and sounds must be in the root directory. the reason your call to file.lua works (im assuming) is the fact that its in the root folder. try moving another_file.lua to the main and try making a call. it should work that way. ^^

Comment: ya.. thats basically what i found out. i just wanted to make sure i wasn't missing anything. the images all work in folders, but the files only work from the root... o well. thanks!

Comment: Subfolders work as of Feb. 23, 2012, just do require("subfolder.filename");

Answer (score 1):

For iOS, this feature has been available since Corona SDK Build 2011.619:

http://blog.anscamobile.com/2011/10/daily-build-feature-lua-files-in-folders/

I expect this feature would come soon for Android.